# If $x_0$ is limit point for $A⊂X$ then y0=f(x0) is limit point for f(A).We have this.Want to prove from this follows that f is continuous at point x0.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

$f$:$X \to Y$

$A$  is any set such that $x_0$ is a limit point of A, then $y_0$ is a limit point of $f(A)$.We have this.Want to prove from this follows that $f$ is continuous at point $x_0$.

For $y_0=f(x_0)$ let's choose any $V$ open neighbourhood and show that $U=f^{-1}(V)$ subset is open  neighbourhood for $x_0$.$W=X$ \ $U$.If $W=\emptyset$ then $U=X$ is open in $X$.So $W\neq\emptyset$.Choose  $x_1 \in \overline{W}$(closure of W).$f(x_1)\in f(\overline{W})\subset \overline{f(W)}\subset\overline{Y/V}=Y/V$

Can you explain how author got $\overline{f(W)}\subset\overline{Y/V}=Y/V$.

I am thinking about $f(X$ / $U$)$\subset$ $f(X)$ \ $f(U)$ but this is true if $f$ is injective and even if was true I am not sure this will help.

Comment: Your question needs clarification. Is $A$ a fixed set or do you mean that if $A$ is **any** set such that $x_0$ is a limit point of $A$, then $y_0$ is a limit point of $f(A)$?

Comment: @KritikerderElche yes your second thought is correct $A$ is any set ...

Comment: Then you should edit your question!

Comment: @KritikerderElche Edited.

Comment: It seems you need the assumption for **all** $x_0$ ansd **all** $A$. Otherwise you cannot conclude $f(x_1) \in \overline{f(W)}$. And do you really want $x_0$ to be a limit point? In that case no isolated point $x_0$ of $X$ admits an $A$ such that $x_0$ is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: And how $f(\overline{W})\subset \overline{f(W)}$?We have this if $f$ is continuous but that is what we want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ were *not* continuous at $x_0$ then there would be a neighbourhood $W$ of $f(x_0)$ so that for **all** neighbourhoods $U \in \mathcal{U}(x_0)$ we'd have $f[U] \nsubseteq W$ (Just the logical negation of the definition). From these data we can find a subset $A$ of $X$ that has $x_0$ as a limit point, while $f(x_0)$ will not be a limit point of $f[A]$. Puzzle on that...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, here is your statement:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be any topological spaces, and let $f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ be a mapping such that, for any set $A \subset X$ and for any point $x \in X$, if $x$ is a limit point of $A$ in $X$, then $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$ in $Y$. Then $f$ is continuous.

Is this what you want to prove? If so, then here is a proof:

> Let $V$ be any closed set of $Y$. We need to show that $f^{-1}(V)$ is a closed set of $X$. Let $p$ be a limit point of $f^{-1}(V)$ in $X$. Then by our hypothesis $f(p)$ is a limit point of the set $f \left( f^{-1}(V) \right)$ in $Y$. But we can show that
> $$
> f \left( f^{-1}(V) \right) \subset V.
> $$
> So $f(p)$ is a limit point of the closed set $V$, which implies that $f(p) \in V$ and hence $p \in f^{-1}(V)$. Thus every limit point of $f^{-1}(V)$ is an element of this set, so $f^{-1}(V)$ is a closed set of $X$ for every closed set $V$  of $Y$. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Hope this helps. Please feel free to ask for any explanation you might still require.

Comment: Thank you @SaaqibMahmood I understand your anser but I am also interested what author meant in my question.

Comment: I think he means a localised version of your global criterion. Just continuity at $x_0$.